# Switching backgrounds of multiple divs in a single keyframe

Tags: css, animation

I am having trouble running a single animation using different divs. I just want to switch between different backgrounds using opacity in animation but i can't run it on different divs in a single animation

I have tried to make this animation on section container it was done but it does not give me transition with it  I also want some transition so that's why I want to run this animation using different divs just like the one made on fivers homepage...!!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply same animation on different elements by just giving all the elements(on which wanted animation) a same class and then selecting that class by dot operator and then in css rule define the animation property. Now, all elements will get this animation.

Suppose in html we have many divs on which we had applied some background color or image. And we want that there is a animation on all of them that firstly the background is light and with time background becomes dark(its original color).

So defining a single keyframe:-

***HTML CODE***

```
    <div class="red same-animation"></div>
    <div class="blue same-animation"></div>
    <div class="green same-animation"></div>
    <div class="yellow same-animation"></div>
```

***CSS CODE***

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    opacity: 0 ;    
}
.red{
    background: red;
}
.green{
    background: green;
}
.blue{
    background: blue;
}
.yellow{
    background: yellow;
}
.same-animation{
    animation: change-opacity 5s ease-in-out 0s 1;
}
div:hover{
    transition: all 5s;
    opacity: 1;
}
@keyframes change-opacity {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

***LINK OF CODE*** -  https://codepen.io/aryansharma-2002/pen/mdpRoqW
So in this example firstly animation will be done in 5second to all divs such that there opacity will increase then all will disappear. Then if hover on any div then it will visible with transition. So tried to explain both concepts.
***If any doubt or suggestion, please comment***